# I'm getting the (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic) error message when trying to connect to my instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance

This is exactly what I get

```bash
$ ssh -i vprofile-prod-key.pem ec2-user@myipaddress
ec2-user@myipaddress: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Nothing seems to work. please help

I'm trying to sign into my instance but I keep running into this problem. I looked at many different solutions and they all failed please help

Comment: Hi @Moladejo. 1 - never put any identifying information in your questions. I'd edit that IP address, and key name were I you. You just gave people the name of a production key and an IP of a server to go with it. 2 - This is less of a programming question and more of a networking/configuration question. You are asking in the wrong stack exchange. Maybe you should try [server fault](https://serverfault.com). 3 - Wether you move the question or not, I'd add information such as what did you try, how exactly it failed, and so on. Good luck regardless.

Comment: I would check for user name - `ec2-user` is used usually for Amazon Linux Image. Are you sure this is your case?